# Translating text in dynamically created element to a different format

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I translate a date created dynamically in the following format:

```
<h3 style="margin-top: 0px" class="departure-datetime">2015-05-04 16:00:00</h3>
```

to something more readable like this:

```
Monday 04 May - 01:00
```

using jQuery?

I understand it involves pointing to the `departure-datetime`, using the `.on` function when the link is opened:

```
$('#search-link').click(function () {
   // code to target all the elements with the class `departure-datetime` 
   // change them to "2015-05-04 16:00:00" to "Monday 04 May - 01:00"
});
```

Comment: Why don't you modify the format at the source?

Comment: @JaredFarrish maybe he doesn't have access to change the source...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Date.parse()` and a few related functions, we can do:

```
$('.departure-datetime').each(function () {
    var value  = $(this).text().trim().split(' '),
        date   = value[1].split(':'),
        day    = value[0].split('-'),
        days   = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'],
        months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];

    date.pop();

    $(this).html(days[new Date(Date.parse('2015-05-04')).getDay()] +' '+day[2]+' '+ months[new Date(Date.parse(value[0])).getMonth()] + ' - ' + date[0] + ':' + date[1]);  

});
```

The result is:

> Monday 04 May - 16:00

Comment: Thanks @vihan1086, how would you make it 24 hours?

Comment: @methuselah Oh that's even easier, I'll update my answer